# Excel If one cell contains a number then highlight that number of cells in a row horizontally

Tags: excel, vba, highlight

I'm looking for a way by VBA or whichever works, even 1 command button but 4-5 processes to be called

```
Call process1
Call process2
End Sub
```

on one click which somehow seems impossible for me as I'm not that advanced in Excel VBA, but hopefully this challenge is a piece of cake for others. The task is to highlight cells horizontally by range based on the formula referring to a cell in Column AM. So "B8" is an amount of 100 which needs to be divided by the number of partitions appearing on "AM3". So 100/6. Now "AM3" is 6 so starting from "C8" a number of 6 cells (Merged in 4's) will be highlighted horizontally. "C9" is relating to "AM4" which is having a value of 9 and will highlight 9 cells (Total of 36 cells since merged) horizontally .

For now this is what i have applied but it limits to only within that range :

```
   Sub HighlightRangeOfCells()
   Dim rng As Range
   For Each rng In Range("C8:AL12")
    If IsNumeric(rng.Value) Then
      If rng.Value <> 0 Then
        rng.Interior.Color = vbRed
     End If
   End If
   Next rng
   End Sub
```

Thanks for your efforts and reply whatever it may be if possible or not.

[image]

Comment: I would recommend centre across cells rather than merging them. I'd also use conditional formatting for this. I don't know what you mean by "row C8" and "row C8 6 cells"

Comment: From Column C Row 8, 6 merged cells (4 cells merged as 1) will be highlighted

Comment: Are there any formula in the range "B8:B12"? Where we can see now 100... Should this value always be 100? Wouldn't it be better to make the process dynamic? I mean, when a value in the above mentioned range will be changed, the respective row to be highlighted according to the raport B/AM? Or if a cell in AM column will be changed to adapt the highlighted cells accordingly?

Comment: No Formula since the value there can be changed any time

Comment: Then, shouldn't it be more convenient to automatically process the appropriate range **when that value is changed**? Without formulas to conditional formatting, which may slow down the process in a big workbook...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [SSlinky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5928161/sslinky), the best way to do this is using conditional formatting. I have created a simple Excel sheet for explaining you how to do such a thing: I have put the formula `=COLUMN()<=$J1` in cell "A1", I have used this formula for conditional formatting, I have dragged to the right, and then I have dragged down.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

As you see, cells get highlighted when their column number in some way corresponds with the value of column "J". All you need to do is replace "J" by "AM" and describe the correspondence as you see fit.

For your information: in the formula, I'm using the reference `$J1`, which means that while dragging and dropping, the row number might change, but the referred column always needs to be "J" (it's a combination of absolute and relative cell references).

Comment: Thank you very much,

This is what im using now 

=IF(COLUMN()<=$AM3+2=TRUE,$B8/$AM3,"")

Comment: Is there anyway to apply this to merged cells of 4 cells each?

Comment: @soldier2gud4me: I have merged cells D2:G4 and entered there the formula `="Row=["&ROW()&"], Column=["&COLUMN()&"]"`, the result was "Row=[2], Column=[4]", so merged cells seem to have the cell reference of the top left cell. Obviously, if your "AM" value tells you only to highlight two cells and you have merged cells over a total of four columns, the entire merged cell will be highlighted.

Comment: Sorry im not so sure How to apply your Row and column formula.

Comment: The `Row()` and `Column()` functions give row or column number of a cell. In case no parameter is filled in, the current cell is used (where the formula is present).

Comment: I think i have busted my brains already. 

=IF(COLUMN()-20=$AM3,$B$8/$AM3,"") this formula gets me to where i want and the value shows as 17 (100/6) BUT i want all other cells before this cell showing a value to automatically show the same $B$8/$AM3 when false. All others after the value true that are blank should stay blank

Comment: Thank you very much i got a fix using this =IF(COLUMN()-20<=$AM3,$B$8/$AM3,"")